# Assign each drawing (line,path,etc.) as elements of a vector, so it can be recalled, used, and edited in looping

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, environment-variables

I want to know how to set drawing elements as variables(elements of a vector/array) so that it can be recalled and modified (in each loop). For example i have a line (`\draw (start) -- (end)`) and want to assign it as the 1st sequence L(1), the 2nd sequence would be the L(2) = line of 0.5 length of L(1), and so forth for L(n).

In this code below, the variable `L` is the length of the line, and `N` is the number of iterations.

*This for creating an image by algorithms*.

**CODE:**

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\N{2};
\def\L{10};
\draw [line width = 1.5pt,magenta] (0,0) -- ({\L},0);
foreach \i in {1,...,\N}{
\draw [line width = 1.5pt,magenta] (0,0) -- ({\L},0);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean about making them elements in a vector as I don't think of vectors as having elements, really. (Probably wrong sense of 'vector'.) An array does, of course, but it doesn't make sense to me in terms of how that fits with your code or what, really you're trying to do.

Comment: @cfr , Thanks for the input. To be spesific, i want to draw a Koch curve using Tikz for good resolution. This requires many iterations, in each will draw lines and also deleting some part of them. I think it is better to import the data points from engineering software and then put it in Latex Tikz. –

Comment: Why not use `decorations.fractals` rather than reinventing the wheel? Koch curves types 1 and 2 are shown on p. 604. The Koch snowflake is also there and one (I guess) non-Koch thing. If that isn't exactly what you need, it will almost certainly be easier to adapt code from the library rather than starting from scratch.

Comment: Or the `lindenmayersystems` I suggest below, which will be much more flexible. But I already suggested that, so I guess you didn't like it for some reason.

Comment: I am still learning how to use it. The reason to make by myself is for combining it with graphic design and i want to make the background transparent.

Comment: I really have no idea why that would be a problem. If you use other software, you can create a vector format or high resolution image and use that - you don't need TikZ for high resolution. If you use TikZ or not, you can have transparency. It is really not clear to me what exactly you want or how you envisage this working exactly. Why would you need to save lines in advance in order to make use of end points exported from other software? But why export them from other software? This feels increasingly like an XY problem. At the least, I'm getting more and more confused :-).

Comment: @cfr . The goal is making a Koch curve or other mathematical aesthetics without using photoshop or other graphic design software (Using Matlab and R for contour plots, Tikz for Koch curve).

To construct Koch curve, certain algorithm with looping (sequences of lines and updating them) is needed. But since you have mentioned the built-in system for this (`decoration.fractals` and  `lindenmayersystems`), i am considering to learn them, but i prefer to make original and flexible algorithms.

Comment: But that's what I'm trying to tell you: you can make the algorithms yourself using the built-in facilities. The `decorations.fractals` are not of much help for this, except as examples. But the `lindenmayersystems` library absolutely is. It does provide some ready-made curves. (I challenge the use of 'curve' but so be it.) But you can write your own algorithms if the ready-made ones aren't what's needed. Of course, if you want to start from scratch, you may. But then you probably wouldn't be asking here. Right now, I don't think you've even bothered to look at the wheels already available.

Comment: I've added an example below. As I understand it, this is what you want to do. If you really want to do it from scratch, start by looking at the source code for the library to get an idea of how you might go about it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure I've understood the question.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\N{5};
  \def\L{10};
  \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using 100*(\N-\i)/(\N-1)] in {1,...,\N}{
    \draw [line width = 1.5pt, magenta!\j!blue] (0,0) -- ({\L/(2^(\i-1))},0);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

will draw a line of length 10, then of length 5, then 2.5, then 1.25, then 0.625. I've also changed the colours incrementally as your code obviously draws them one atop the other so they'd look just like one line of length 10 otherwise.

[image: incremental lines]

You can also create `pic`s to store code which might be useful here. For example

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\N{5};
  \def\L{10};
  \tikzset{%
    L/.pic={%
      \pgfmathsetmacro\j{100*(\N-#1)/(\N-1)}
      \draw [line width = 1.5pt, magenta!\j!blue, pic actions] (0,0) -- ({\L/(2^(#1-1))},0);
    }
  }
  \foreach \i in {1,...,\N}
  {%
    \pic [rotate={\i*360/\N}] at (0,0) {L=\i};
    \pic [rotate={(\N-\i+1)*360/\N}] at ({\N-\i},\i) {L=\i};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

produces

[image: 10 <code>pic</code>s]

The various elements aren't stored. Rather the instructions for creating an element are stored and then executed with the given variable when and where they are called. The `(0,0)` in the stored instructions is understood as the point at which the `pic` is located. So `pic at (3,2)` will be drawn as a little picture with origin at `(3,2)`. `pic`s are likely to be most useful if the elements you want to draw are more complex. If they are just lines, as here, they are overkill.

Have you looked at the `lindenmayersystems` TikZ library? This library seems essentially perfect for what you want to do, as I currently understand it on the basis of discussion in comments.

Here's an example which is a slight variant of one from the manual:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}% based on example from manual 647
  [l-system={step=1.75pt, order=5, angle=80}]
  \pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{my algorithm}{
    \symbol{X}{\pgflsystemdrawforward}
    \symbol{Y}{\pgflsystemdrawforward}
    \rule{X -> Y-X+Y}
    \rule{Y -> X+Y-X}
  }
  \draw [magenta] (0,0) l-system
  [l-system={my algorithm, axiom=+++X, anchor=south west}];
  \draw [blue] (3,2) l-system
  [l-system={my algorithm, axiom=X, anchor=north east}];
  \draw [blue!50!magenta] (0,0) l-system
  [l-system={my algorithm, axiom=+Y, anchor=south east}];
  \draw [blue!25!magenta] (1,3) l-system
  [l-system={my algorithm, axiom=--Y, anchor=north east}];
  \draw [blue!75!magenta] (2,0) l-system
  [l-system={my algorithm, axiom=--X, anchor=north east}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: custom algorithm]

As can be seen, the library supports the writing of new sets of rules and the creation of paths constructed by applying those rules to axioms. In addition to a set of default symbols, custom symbols may be defined to draw/move in other ways and/or to control the way in which the path 'grows'.

Comment: Yes @cfr , this is what i wanted for a spesific case (for creating symmetrical patterns). But for saving lines or graphic elements by arrays so that each of them can be recalled and edited (even deleted) is not possible in Latex environment, i presume..

Comment: @user55935 I don't really understand what you mean. That is rather different from using an algorithm to construct a pattern. You can save something to a `\savebox` and then use it. You can change what's in the `\savebox`. In TikZ, you can use `pic`s as I show here. But all of that is ridiculous overkill if you just want a lines. And if this line is to be different (thicker, thinner, longer, shorter, different colour etc.), then obviously it is a new line. I don't understand what you are trying to do or why it would be in any way useful.